# Apparently undefined variable in Numerical Recipes

Tags: c++, undefined

I am trying to use Numerical Recipes, 3rd Edition, Amoeba.h and cannot find where a variable is being defined. Here is the beginning of the code:

```
struct Amoeba {
    const Doub ftol;
    Int nfunc;
    Int mpts;
    Int ndim;
    Doub fmin;
    VecDoub y;
    MatDoub p;
    Amoeba(const Doub ftoll) : ftol(ftoll) {}
    template <class T>
    VecDoub minimize(VecDoub_I &point, const Doub del, T &func)
    {
        VecDoub dels(point.size(),del);
        return minimize(point,dels,func);
    }
    template <class T>
    VecDoub minimize(VecDoub_I &point, VecDoub_I &dels, T &func)
    {
        Int ndim=point.size();
        MatDoub pp(ndim+1,ndim);           <--------- XXXXXXX
        for (Int i=0;i<ndim+1;i++) {
            for (Int j=0;j<ndim;j++)
                pp[i][j]=point[j];
            if (i !=0 ) pp[i][i-1] += dels[i-1];
        }
        return minimize(pp,func);
    }
    template <class T>
    VecDoub minimize(MatDoub_I &pp, T &func)
    {
        const Int NMAX=5000;
        const Doub TINY=1.0e-10;
        Int ihi,ilo,inhi;
        mpts=pp.nrows();
        ndim=pp.ncols();
        VecDoub psum(ndim),pmin(ndim),x(ndim);
        p=pp;
.....
```

On the line marked with the X's the variable pp is used but does not appear to be defined. In the next method, pp is used as an argument variable defined as `MatDoub_I &pp` (MatDoub is a class that implements matrices), but in the first function it appears to be undefined. Is this just an error on the part of the authors or is there something I do not understand about C++ here?

Note that just p is defined as `MatDoub` above. Does that mean pp is the same things as (MatDoub)(MatDoub)? That violates my understanding of C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
 MatDoub pp(ndim+1,ndim);
```

`pp` is not being *used* it is being declared and constructed. After this line `pp` is an initialized object and subsequent uses are fine. You can find more information about [`constructor initialization` here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: Oh, I see it is a constructor.

Comment: @TylerDurden don't beat yourself up over it